# Does [DllImport] imports whole DLL lib each time?

Tags: c#, c, dllimport

I have recently build the following C code:

```c
//
// No header file due to this file is going to be compiled to single DLL
//
 
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
#define BUFFER_SIZE 2500
 
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int position;
} WriterBuffer;
 
WriterBuffer buffer = {{}, 0};
 
//region Buffer management
 
void Destroy(void)
{
    buffer.position = 0;
    free(buffer.buffer);
}
 
bool EnsureCapacity(int value)
{
    return buffer.position + value <= BUFFER_SIZE;
}
 
void RawWriteByte(char value)
{
    buffer.buffer[buffer.position++] = value;
}
 
void RawWriteBytes(const char* value, int count)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        buffer.buffer[buffer.position++] = value[i];
    }
}
 
//endregion
 
 
//region Buffer operations
 
WriterBuffer GetBuffer()
{
    return buffer;
}
 
//endregion
 
 
//region Primitive type writers
 
void WriteByte(unsigned char value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(1)) return;
    RawWriteByte(value);
}
 
void WriteSByte(signed char value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(1)) return;
    RawWriteByte((unsigned char) value);
}
 
void WriteChar(char value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(1)) return;
    RawWriteByte(value);
}
 
void WriteBool(bool value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(1)) return;
    RawWriteByte(value ? 1 : 0);
}
 
void WriteShort(short value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(2)) return;
    RawWriteByte((char) value);
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 8));
}
 
void WriteUShort(unsigned short value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(2)) return;
    RawWriteByte((char) value);
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 8));
}
 
void WriteInt(int value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(4)) return;
    RawWriteByte((char) value);
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 8));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 16));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 24));
}
 
void WriteUInt(unsigned int value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(4)) return;
    RawWriteByte((char) value);
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 8));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 16));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 24));
}
 
void WriteLong(long value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(8)) return;
    RawWriteByte((char) value);
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 8));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 16));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 24));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 32));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 40));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 48));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 56));
}
 
void WriteULong(unsigned long value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(8)) return;
    RawWriteByte((char) value);
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 8));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 16));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 24));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 32));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 40));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 48));
    RawWriteByte((char) (value >> 56));
}
 
union
{
    float floatVal;
    unsigned int intVal;
} FloatConverter;
 
void WriteFloat(float value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(4)) return;
    FloatConverter.floatVal = value;
    WriteUInt(FloatConverter.intVal);
}
 
union
{
    double doubleVal;
    unsigned long longVal;
} DoubleConverter;
 
void WriteDouble(double value)
{
    if(!EnsureCapacity(8)) return;
    DoubleConverter.doubleVal = value;
    WriteULong(DoubleConverter.longVal);
}
 

//endregion
```

And I want to use this thing in the corresponding C# NetworkWriter class.

Of course, my first thought is to use the [DllImport] for each method I want to use in the C# code.

But, I asked myself a question - will each [DllImport] overwrite the `buffer` (right below typedef)?

Or I do that native code implementation totally wrong & I should include that code in a different way?

Comment: Shared global variable sounds like a bad idea. Constrains you to a single thread. Why not have the caller allocate the buffer and pass it in. Also, it would surely be cleaner to use pure C# here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I haven't thinked about this in this way. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: But still, my question - does each [DllImport] loads whole library each time it's required?

Comment: No, it’s only loaded once.

Comment: These are shared libraries. The process loads a single instance of each DLL.

Comment: When you use DllImport you are creating a definition to call a method on the execution stack.  A dll contains a symbol list of where public items are located.  The DllImport looks up the entry point for the start location in Dll.  It also defines the input variable to the method which get pushed on the execution stack before the call is made to the method.  Before you call the method(s) you must allocate an instance of the Struct in c#.  If you reuse the instance than the buffer gets overridden.  If you allocate a new instance of the struct before each call then each struct is unique.

Comment: @jdweng make this an answer